# How can I join tables specified in a separate list of tables in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database

I'm making some monthly reports, and I can't change the design of the database.

I have a table which kinda contains a list of other tables in the database - a list that changes monthly. For example:

```
type | counter    | other_irrelevant
-----+------------+-----------------
 001 | 0000003010 | stuff...
 001 | 0000003011 | stuff...
 090 | 0000000112 | stuff...
 090 | 0000000113 | stuff...
```

For each of those 4 entries in the list, there are corresponding tables in the database:

- `ZZ0010000003010`
- `ZZ0010000003011`
- `ZZ0900000000112`
- `ZZ0900000000113`

Based on the "list of tables", I'd like to join these tables. Is that doable in any way without using dynamic SQL, pointers, or other looping hacks? If not, what would be the least messy dynamic SQL solution for this?

Comment: Nope. You have to use dynamic for this. There is no alternative.

Comment: Yes, this is the definition of dynamic sql :-).  It also has lots of answers already, such as this one:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210180/sql-dynamic-select-statement-from-values-stored-in-a-table